# How to bring partner over to Germany as a non-EU citizen, German Permanent Resident?

Tags: germany, working-visas, immigration

I currently live in the US, but I have permanent residency in Germany. I'm neither a US or EU citizen. My partner is a US citizen.

I'd like to move back to Germany and bring my partner along. We're not married - but willing to get married before our move in case we need to.

My question is how can I, as a permanent resident holder in Germany, bring my partner along? Can I sponsor him for a visa? Will he be able to work? I've been scouring the immigration and consulates websites for Germany and all the information I can find is for EU or German citizens bringing partners into Germany - but I am neither.

My partner does not hold a job in one of the "required skills" type of industries, but he does speak some German. Ideally I'd like to get him a work visa, and then find him a job in his field once he arrives to Germany. We're not concerned with being able to find a job, but rather having a work visa before looking for one as his field is not one in which sponsorship happens.

Answer (score 5):

What you would be looking for is called “*Familiennachzug*” (“family reunification”). You can find a lot of information about it on the [website of the federal agency for migration and refugees](http://www.bamf.de/DE/Migration/Arbeiten/Familiennachzug/familiennachzug-node.html) ([same page in English](http://www.bamf.de/EN/Migration/Arbeiten/Familiennachzug/familiennachzug-node.html)).

Marrying would probably help and knowing (basic) German is also usually a requirement but special skills are not. Your own situation in Germany is however very important: You need to have a job or sufficient income to support your partner/family (*Lebensunterhalt*) and appropriate accommodation (*Wohnraum*) to qualify for “Familiennachzug”.

Your being currently in the US could therefore be a problem (incidentally, I don't know exactly what the rules are in Germany but I would be concerned about losing your permanent residency right if you stay too long in the US). I think the usual procedure would be for you to move to Germany first, find a job and accommodation and then apply for your partner to join you.

Particularly relevant to your question is this:

> Der Aufenthaltstitel von nachziehenden Familienangehörigen berechtigt auch zur Ausübung einer Erwerbstätigkeit (§ 27 Abs. 5 AufenthG).

This means that if you sponsor your partner for this kind of visa/title, he will be allowed to work in Germany.